# How to compute this integration?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Afternoon,

I am keeping in studying on exam and stumbled upon this integral (I am asked to count it with per-parted procedure) -  $\int {2x}\arctan x\,dx$

How should I proceed the "$\arctan x$" function?

Will be grateful for every advise here :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\int2x\arctan x\ dx=\arctan x\int2x\ dx-\int\left(\frac{d(\arctan x)}{dx}\cdot\int2x\ dx\right)dx$$

$$=\arctan x\cdot x^2-\int\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\ dx$$

Now $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=1-\frac1{1+x^2}$

Comment: Thank you `lab bhattacharjee`, but what's the per-partes substitution here (u, v)?

Comment: @user2932090, First term $u=\arctan x,$ second $v=2x$

Comment: Your notation is rather peculiar, I must say. One normally writes $\int u\, dv=uv-\int v\,du$ etc. so here it would be $\int \arctan x d(x^2) = x^2\arctan x -\int x^2d(\arctan x) =x^2\arctan x -\int\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}dx$ etc.

Comment: @MPW, My notation $$\int uv\ dx=u\int v\ dx-\int\left(\frac{du}{dx}\cdot \int v\ dx\right)dx$$

Comment: Yes--that's what I am calling peculiar. Not the normal formula one uses for integration by parts. I'm not saying it's wrong, just an odd way to write it.